# Не могу создать рабочий свой event в WinForms. при потыке подписать к событию метод показывает ошибку

Tags: c#, winforms

```
   public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    User user;
    public delegate void Note(string message, string title, EventHandler e);
    public event Note NoteEvent;

    public MainForm(User userIn)
    {
        user = userIn;
        InitializeComponent();
        this.LoadVidgets();
        NoteEvent += PopUpNotifiactionShow("Часы работают", "Уведосление о часах", accountLabel_Click);

    }
```

Есть в Form1 делегат и событие.

но при поптыке к этому событию присобачить метод выбивает ошибку.
Что я делаю не так, и как создать такое событие?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что такое accountLabel_Click? и не вынуждайте перепечатывать код с картинки, вставляйте код текстом, пожалуйста. Попробуйте `new EventHandler(accountLabel_Click)`

Comment: Я это событие (accountLabel_Click) убирал вообще из параметров, но ошибка не в этом. Ошибка в том что NoteEvent как то не так создан. Он почему то ругается на тип.

Comment: Убедитесь, что нет конфликта имен.

Comment: Спасибо, но уже разобрался в чем дело. Это я ступил:) Уже сам дал ответ на свой вопрос:)

Comment: Поэтом и надо код текстом прикладывать. Я на скрине не сразу смекнул, в чем дело.

Answer (score 2):

вместо:

```
NoteEvent += PopUpNotifiactionShow("Часы работают", "Уведосление о часах", accountLabel_Click);
```

просто подписываем на событие метод:

```
this.NoteEvent += PopUpNotifiactionShow;
```

потом в нужном методе вызываем событие:

```
NoteEvent?.Invoke("Текст уведомления", "Заголовок уведомления", accountLabel_Click);
```